# Is it true that $A\cap U \subset A$ is an open set in $A$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topolocical space and $A\subset X$ such that $A$ is a closed set in $X$.

Take $U\subset X$ such that $U$ is an open set in $X$.

Is it true that $A\cap U \subset A$ is an open set in $A$ ?

Comment: This is the definition of the Subspace topology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably by "open in $A$" you mean "open in the subspace topology on $A$".

It is true by definition of the [subspace (or relative) topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology); indeed, $A$ can be any set, not just a closed set! Remember that the open sets in the subspace topology on $A$ are exactly those of the form $$U\cap A$$ for $U\subseteq X$ open.